# CodeIgniter change the page indexes

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is there a way to change the page indexes with codeigniter witch routes ?

Page

some/page/url?index1=**thing**&item=second

to

Showing only the

**thing**

If it can't be done with routes, how it will be done with htaccess ?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using query strings under Codeigniter.

Read the Codeigniter documentation for more information on how you should be doing it:
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html